# Check if post is closed in SEDE

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

How do you check if a post is closed in SEDE? I can get a list of all posts and visually see what ones have been closed (they have a date).

```
Select Id from posts where ClosedDate (need help for this part)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the field is not null like so:

```
Select Id from posts where ClosedDate is not null
```

As you seem to be interested in questions (answers can't be closed) you might want to add an extra expression to only select questions by adding posttype_id = 1 where 1 means question and 2 would mean answer.

```
Select Id from posts 
where ClosedDate is not null
and posttypeid = 1 -- q
```

See [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for more explanation of the schema and the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) for help with basic queries.

Comment: Thanks. I can't use newlines since space is limited (PPCG)

Comment: without newlines it works as well @DownChristopher

Comment: ok thanks. Now to finish my SEDE. Just have to grab a random result